# Code hyperlink not found in Sharepoint Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, css

I'm trying to edit my .aspx page in SharePoint Designer, and there are many underlined codes which are probably links to codes in other pages. Here is an example:

[image]

When I click on one of those hyperlinks, it shows me the error message:

[image]

Why does this message occur? Is there any way to bypass this error message and get to the **inner** codes?

By the way, I am very sure that these hyperlinks (classes/ids) have codes in them because when I used Google's developer tools (right click > inspect > go to element tab and inspect the code), there were many **inner** codes found under those classes/ids that are hyperlinked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does this message occur?**

It's normal behavior in SharePoint Designer, By default, all IDs and classes have Hyperlink, and you got `Code hyperlink not found` especially with IDs in case there is no CSS style linked to it!

> **Note:** in the CSS style sheet the **id** start with  `#` and the **class** start with `.` So not all CSS styles that are shown in (Google Developer Tools (F12)) considered a defined style for **Id** if not started with `#`.

**Is there any way to bypass this error message and get to the inner codes?**

For classes/Ids, you can use `CTRL+Click` to get the inner CSS that by default stored in `Corev15.css` or in any other CSS file based on the current page. (Eg: in Oslo master page, a lot of the built-in CSS has been stored in `oslo.css`)

> **Note:** It's not recommended to edit the `Corev15.css` or built-in files, So to change these styles you should override it based on your requirements using `!important;` as the following
>
> **Ex:**

```
.ms-core-needIEFilter .ms-bgSelected{
background-color:transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are links indeed, which are supposed to be opened with `Ctrl+click`. I can tell that I've often seen the same warning dialog as your screen capture shows, so it's nothing to be alerted of.

This is an educated guess as I can't (at least quickly) find any documentation about the subject, but I assume that the links can't be opened because the linked code is located in another site repository, site level and/or server. As an example, if you attempt to open `id="pageContentTitle"`, it maybe should take you to a `corev15.css`-file where this id has some defined styling. However, this sort of files are hosted at the system's top level, which wouldn't be the same hierarchical area as the source code you are currently seeing in your SP Designer. You may have noticed that each time you open a new SP site in your SP Designer, you'll authenticate to the site. SP Designer doesn't seem to be a good tool in efficient code linking, or then it's just (too) careful with the authentications.